# MongoDB C driver does not return any results for aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-c

I have following SQL query:

SELECT SUM("PAYMENT_HISTORY"."AMOUNT_PAID") FROM "PAYMENT_HISTORY" WHERE (("PAYMENT_HISTORY".YEAR >= 2011) AND ("PAYMENT_HISTORY".YEAR <= 2013) AND ("PAYMENT_HISTORY"."AMOUNT_PAID" >= 500.0))

same SQL after conversion was ran from MongoDB shell and it returns value.

db.PAYMENT_HISTORY.aggregate(
  { $match : {$and: [{YEAR: {$gte : 2011}}, {YEAR: {$lte : 2013}}, {AMOUNT_PAID: {$gte: 500.00}}]}},
  { $group : {_id : "POLICY_ID", total:{$sum : "$AMOUNT_PAID"}}}
 )

While i am trying to run through MongoDB C driver, it doesn't return any results.

```
int status = mongo_client( mNoSQLConnection, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );
if (status != MONGO_OK){
    switch (mNoSQLConnection->err) {
        case MONGO_CONN_NO_SOCKET:  printf( "no socket\n" ); 
        case MONGO_CONN_FAIL:       printf( "connection failed\n" ); 
        case MONGO_CONN_NOT_MASTER: printf( "not master\n" ); 
    }
}
else{
    bson query[1], b_result[1];
    mongo_cursor cursor[1];
    bson_init( query );
        bson_append_string(query, "aggregate", "PAYMENT_HISTORY");
            bson_append_start_object(query, "$match");
                bson_append_start_array(query, "$and");
                        bson_append_start_object(query, "$gte");
                            bson_append_int(query, "YEAR", 2011);
                        bson_append_finish_object(query);
                        bson_append_start_object(query, "$lte");
                            bson_append_int(query, "YEAR", 2013);
                        bson_append_finish_object(query);
                        bson_append_start_object(query, "$gte");
                            bson_append_double(query, "AMOUNT_PAID", 500.00);
                        bson_append_finish_object(query);
                bson_append_finish_array(query);
            bson_append_finish_object(query);
            bson_append_start_object(query, "$group");
                bson_append_string(query, "_id", "POLICY_ID");
                bson_append_string(query, "total", "total");
                    bson_append_start_object(query, "$sum");
                        bson_append_start_object(query, "$AMOUNT_PAID");
                        bson_append_finish_object(query);
                    bson_append_finish_object(query);
            bson_append_finish_object(query);
    bson_finish( query );

    bson_print(query);

    int status1;
    status1 = mongo_run_command(mNoSQLConnection, "DB_NAME", query, b_result);
    if (MONGO_OK != status1 )
    {
    }
    else
    {
        /*command results*/
        bson_print(b_result);
    }

    bson_destroy( query );
    mongo_cursor_destroy( cursor );

}
```

Can somebody help me in figuring out mistake/s in above code?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `bson_print`?

Comment: Right before the first `$match`, you need to define an array with the pipeline: `bson_append_start_array(b, "pipeline");`

Comment: @WiredPrairie 
output of bson_print is as and will update this after trying pipeline:

` aggregate : 2   PAYMENT_HISTORY
 $match : 3   
  $and : 4   
   $gte : 3   
    YEAR : 16   2011

   $lte : 3   
    YEAR : 16   2013

   $gte : 3   
    AMOUNT_PAID : 1   500.000000



 $group : 3   
  _id : 2   POLICY_ID
  total : 2   total
  $sum : 3   
   $AMOUNT_PAID : 3 `

Comment: Did you try adding the pipeline element?

Comment: Despite the detractors to what I believe is a fair answer I encourage you to look at [BCON](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/bcon.html) as a way of improving the legibility of what you are doing. It's structure is a lot more analogous to the pure shell syntax you gave in your question.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks for direction. I tried pipeline aswell but Mongo DB crashed with following error with pipeline:
`Wed Feb 12 06:30:03 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54299 #1 (1 connection now open)
Wed Feb 12 06:30:03 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54300 #2 (2 connections now open)
Wed Feb 12 06:30:03 [conn1] ERROR: Uncaught exception, terminating
Wed Feb 12 06:30:03 dbexit: `

I will read again about aggregation in MongoDB, will re-write code and update this.

Comment: I'd like to help further, but since it's such a bear to get the C driver compiled on Windows, I just can't do any testing like I'd normally do to try to help. (Sorry).